# Android SearchLayout is not appearing properly in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, menuitem, searchview

I want to Make `SearchView` with `RecyclerView` My filtering function working perfect,but SearchLayout is not appearing properly.

I referred this [link](https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/03/searchview-with-recyclerview.html) to integrate SearchView with RecyclerView

Here is my Menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.learn2crack.recyclerviewsearch.MainActivity">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:title="Search"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    </menu>
```

Here is My XML design code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/appyellow"
    tools:context="app.msupply.com.ideaurben.Activity.Report_Here">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code:

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarmenu);
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // toolbar.setTitle("Report Search");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Report Search");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);




 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        search(searchView);
     //   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;


    }
```

I want to make Searchview as same in that provided link. I followed almost the same but it is not coming properly. Here is my [image]

Comment: you want toolbar white when searchview is open?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira yes you are correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with your code is that you are using `LinearLayout` instead of a `CoordinatorLayout` 
All such kind of animations is the result of the latter one. 
Enjoy.

Comment: Did you set some behaviors too? Coz without that, it won't work.

Comment: Looks like you have disabled `nestedScrolling` under `RecyclerView` any idea, why?

Comment: Omg, CoordinatorLayout is working fine thank you so much with coordinator layout. 
one more query I have like, what is that I want to do to change text color as black and back arrow as black in the same searchview.

Comment: Hi i need to change `searchview` text color,you gave link for Toolbar change color..Please guide me.

Comment: You mean the Hint Color  i.e. "Search Here"?

Comment: M yes ur are correct, and also that `back arrow image` color i need to change.

Answer (score 0):

set searchview color TRANSPARENT like below

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        search(searchView);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Let me check sir.@Omi

Comment: Really? That's how you were gonna fix it Omi?

Comment: @Omi I tried sir, still not able to fix.i was trying past 4 hr.